# Derive all image styles when user uploading

Tags: nodes, media, hooks

I have several image styles defined but only thumbnail and medium styles(images) can be derived from the original image.

I know those two styles are set in the "manage field" of image and my usage is not going to switch thumbnail nor medium to other styles. My use-case is to generate all styles when/after users upload.

Please help, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the [Image Style Warmer](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_style_warmer) module is what you want.

> The Image Style Warmer module provides options to create image styles
> during upload or via queue worker. So configured image derivates
> already exists when they are requested.
>
> - Pre-generate configured image styles on image upload or crop change.
> - Pre-generate configured image styles via queue worker.

Comment: Thank you for answering. This is an old system of the company and it doesn't have this module but somehow the production will generate all styles after the user clicks the save button. We do have the flysystem installed and I believe my local is in the same branch as our production.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the functionality without installing the "warmer" module?

Comment: You an look at how that module does it, and incorporate the methodology into your module.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know.